# emulator doesn't show in device view in ddms

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, ddms

When I try to debug using one of the configurations that I've set up (for example Android233), the emulator never actually launches. I just see a little green icon in my task bar that says "launching Android233," but it never launches.  I've let it sit there for hours and it never does anything.  I don't know if this is related, but my emulators don't show in device view in the DDMS perspective.  I have a physical Android device, which shows up in device view.  My question is, what is happenin' and how can I fix it?

Thanks for taking the time to read my question :)

I thought I had the problem figured out, but it stopped working again.  Here's more information: When I run my debug configuration, in the lower right corner of my Ecplipse windows it says:
"Launching MyDebugConfig (100%)" and then there's a green icon next to it.
I looked in task manager and the emulator is not in there.  I looked in DDMS and my AVD is not listed and there is nothing in the LogCat or Thread or anything else for that matter.  I have my debug configuration set to prompt me to pick a device, but it never does that.  It just loads my AVD, even if I have my phone connected (which is visible in DDMS).  I'm so stumped.  I've had this problem since I started using Eclipse and I don't know what to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
Go to DDMS Perspective =>Click View menu=>reset adb
```

Answer (score 3):

> If Your genymotion virtual device is not seen in android device monitor then just try this.
>   1. start android studio 
>   2. start Android Device Monitor
>   3. Lastly start the genymotion virtual device it will appear

Answer (score 1):

The emulator won't show up in the DDMS section until its running.

The emulator won't lunch probably because you misconfigured it, currently the lunch dialog of the emulator doesn't support error messages, however you can get the lunch stack trace while you try to lunch the emulator via Eclipse.

Disconnect your physical device, run your project and select the emulator. you should see an error message on DDMS console.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  I deleted all of  my AVDs, created new ones and new debug/run configurations.  I found out that I had the target build wrong for my AVDs, so I changed it to the right target.  All is happy in Android-land now :)

Comment: I would vote for you, but I just joined today and don't have enough points.

Answer (score 0):

If you in Windows try run (after starting emulator)

```
adb.exe kill-server
adb.exe start-server
```

and wait for restarting your adb